# Unable to extract out name in 4 level deep nested JSON array

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to create android app that shows details about the restaurants. I have parseJSON function which takes string json as an argument. What I am trying to do for now is to show name of individual restaurants in the json below. I am able to extract individual restaurant(3 levels deep) and print them out through log.d console but I am not able to extract out the individual restaurant's name. Here is  the code

```
public void parseJSON(String jsonQuery){
        //Parsing JSON
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonQuery);
            if (jsonObject != null){
                JSONArray restaurants = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject restaurant = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (restaurant != null){
                        String tempName = restaurant.getString("name");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Restaurant name: " + tempName);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception catched: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my json file.

```
{
  "results_found": 1281966,
  "results_start": 0,
  "results_shown": 2,
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 16607974
        },
        "apikey": "123456789",
        "id": "16607974",
        "name": "Bassine Specialty Cheese",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/bass-vic/bassine-specialty-cheese-bass?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "2125 Bass Hwy",
          "locality": "Bass",
          "city": "Bass",
          "city_id": 1341,
          "latitude": "-38.4833750000",
          "longitude": "145.4670320000",
          "zipcode": "3995",
          "country_id": 14,
          "locality_verbose": "Bass, Bass"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "Ice Cream",
        "average_cost_for_two": 7,
        "price_range": 1,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "2.9",
          "rating_text": "Average",
          "rating_color": "FFBA00",
          "votes": "5"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/bass-vic/bassine-specialty-cheese-bass/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/bass-vic/bassine-specialty-cheese-bass/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/16607974",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/bass-vic/bassine-specialty-cheese-bass/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    },
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 17649424
        },
        "apikey": "3d93604b4a84d85f374f39ea3b644132",
        "id": "17649424",
        "name": "Schobels' Restaurant",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/columbus-tx/schobels-restaurant-columbus?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "2020 Milam St 78934",
          "locality": "Columbus",
          "city": "Columbus",
          "city_id": 9241,
          "latitude": "29.6965000000",
          "longitude": "-96.5405000000",
          "zipcode": "78934",
          "country_id": 216,
          "locality_verbose": "Columbus, Columbus"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "German, Southern",
        "average_cost_for_two": 25,
        "price_range": 2,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "4.0",
          "rating_text": "Very Good",
          "rating_color": "5BA829",
          "votes": "164"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/columbus-tx/schobels-restaurant-columbus/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/columbus-tx/schobels-restaurant-columbus/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/17649424",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/columbus-tx/schobels-restaurant-columbus/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Error which I am getting:
org.json.JSONException: No value for name

Comment: check my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jsonQuery` contain `JsonObject` inside `JsonObject` named `restaurant` so you need to get JsonObject from `JSONObject restaurant = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);`

Like `JSONObject restaurantsJSONObject =restaurant.getJSONObject("restaurant");`

Try below example to get name from object

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonQuery);
    if (jsonObject != null){
        JSONArray restaurants = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++){
            JSONObject restaurant = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject restaurantsJSONObject =restaurant.getJSONObject("restaurant");
            if(restaurantsJSONObject.has("name")) {
                String tempName = restaurantsJSONObject.getString("name");
                Log.d(TAG, "Restaurant name: " + tempName);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Exception catched: " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is working now! I am still confused about these object orders! Can you tell a bit more about them?

Comment: @killerprince182 goto http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and copy paste your json

Comment: then check the structure of your  response json

Comment: you can see restaurants array inside restaurants array you will find some object

Comment: click on one of jsonObject you will see it contain one more `restaurant` object